# Hide totally the sidebar when pressing the toggle button in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

Is there any way to hide totally the sidebar when pressing the toggle button at the top of the dashboard? Right now a a part of the sidebar remains.

```
#app.r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(

    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
    ),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `sidebar_fullCollapse=TRUE` in to the `dashboardPagePlus` command to fully collapse it